# How can I solve Null Pointer Exception error in Android Studio using Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a project using Firebase Auth and Realtime Database and I recieved the error

`com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.`

when trying to create a new account and fetch the user's data (I want to send that to another activity through an intent). I believe this error was solved by uninstalling the app and running again.

EDITED: I ran again and now the error is a Null Pointer Exception on the User created. Here's the new error as it appears in the Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.stud.scriptreality.classes.User.getEmail()' on a null object reference
        at com.stud.scriptreality.Register$1$1.onDataChange(Register.java:82)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.2.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The thing is when checking the list of users in Firebase Auth, the user appears to be created, but my Android app crashes.

I set the database refference like this:

```
firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
myRef = database.getReference("users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
```

In the code below I have the listener for fetching the data from Realtime Database and myRef is the refference to the database. I believe the problem is here somewhere, since the registration of the Firebase User is working.

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String useremail = dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(User.class).getEmail(); //this is line 82
        String userpassword = dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(User.class).getPassword();
        String userjob = dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(User.class).getJob();
        user = new User(useremail,userpassword,userjob);

        if(user!=null){
            switch (userjob){
                case "Screenwriter":
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeScreenwriter.class);
                    intent.putExtra("user",user);
                    startActivity(intent);
                case "Producer":
                    Intent intentP = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeProducer.class);
                    intentP.putExtra("user",user);
                    startActivity(intentP);
                case "Scenograph":
                    Intent intentSp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeScenograph.class);
                    intentSp.putExtra("user",user);
                    startActivity(intentSp);
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Invalid job.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "User null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, databaseError.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
```

I created the User object like that, because trying to recieve it directly from Firebase gives me a null object and I don't really know why.

Saving the user in the Realtime Database is the work of this function, which I called right before the listener:

```
private void writeNewUser( String email, String password, String job) {
        User user = new User(email, password, job);
        myRef.setValue(user);
    }
```

Is it wrong to create a user with other attributes except email and password? In the Firebase documentation I only see examples using these two fields, but I really need to separate the users with that attribute, because I'm developing something different for each of them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you dump the rest of the error log as well? As in lines preceeding and following?

Comment: Hi! The buffer overflow error was solved by uninstalling the app, but now I recieve another error. I edited the question with this one. The problem remains: the user is created, but when trying to fetch the data, I get null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
```

instead of:

```
dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(User.class)
```

Your reference already contains "users" and "user id"

> dataSnapshot.child("users").getValue(User.class) = null